# Do raindrops spin as they fall?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I'm wondering if a drop of water starts to spin as it falls.  Also, does this spin increase until the drop slings itself apart or does it have a terminal spin velocity?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP shows no research efforts.

Comment: Dear MaryAnne. Have you done any research on this? Please say if you have. A quick search myself shows that info is not obviously available on this question and a definitive answer is far from obvious. I agree with the general gist of most of the answers that, from a general physicist's standpoint, it *seems highly unlikely* that raindrops would spin owing to symmetry considerations - there is therefore no obvious mechanism to set up torques on falling drops and therefore transfer angular momentum to them. But it would be very unwise to answer this question definitively unless one had .....

Comment: .... done specific research on the topic: a raindrop falling through turbulent winds is a highly complex thing, so I think an acceptable answer would need to cite either experimental results or a decent numerical computer simulation of the problem. There *may* (again I think it unlikely) be some mechanism whereby a small asymmetry in a drop is reinforced in a self organising way such that torque on the drop arises.

Comment: [images of raindrops](http://www.digitalcameraworld.com/2012/12/16/rain-photography-how-to-take-pictures-of-raindrops/) . A kind of spin when the drop is not spheric or if it contains a not symmetric impurity ? [a resource about raindrops shapes](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-1201154/Solved-Why-raindrops-alike.html)

Answer (score 4):

They might have some initial spin when they are starting to fall, but gradually frictional forces cause them to lose their rotational kinetic energy until they are close to zero (assuming ideal conditions of constant air pressure). However if there is no opposing torque on the drop so as to keep it spinning, it will continue to lose energy till its angular velocity drops down to zero.

Answer (score 3):

A water drop doesn't spin during free fall. This is because-

1. Water is a fluid and so it adapts to the force applied on it by the surroundings. This means that when a water droplet falls it takes a very symmetrical shape w.r.t every possible direction of drag it experiences during the fall.
2. The net Torque it would experience would be zero as it is cancelled out by opposite forces(because of symmetry). 
   **So, the drop falls without any spin!**

(I am interested in knowing what brought you to conclude that a water droplet spins during a free fall)
**Update regarding Coriolis effect-**

[image]

As you see OA > OB. In same time point A has to travel 2pi(OA) as B which has to travel 2pi(OB). As speed is distance/time, Speed of A > Speed of B. This is the cause of toilet swirls (which actually doesn't happen in toilets and drains as AB is not very large and other factors come into play as you watched in the video).

Comment: I saw water spinning as it falls out of a hose/faucet.  I was wondering if water in frefall would spin or if the pipe or confined space attached to the earth was necessary...  I think the water can fall along a natural path through the air but when going down a drain is deflected from the natural path causing spin.

Comment: @MaryAnneRyals is this about 'water drains clockwise in one hemisphere and anticlockwise in other' ? (because it has a pretty decent explanation)

Comment: It is definately related to that.  Does freefalling water spin or does there have to be a drain? If freefalling water in a stream tends to spin wouldnt a freefalling raindrop tend to spin? If the water coming out of my garden hose is pointing down it seems like it spins.  Now how is that affected if i squirt the water up?  Will it spin the opposite way?  Maybe that is getting into something slightly different...

Comment: @MaryAnneRyals I could explain all that but there is will help you understand better (but this doesnt happen in free fall! because not enough radius) - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ihv4f7VMeJw

Comment: Ok that helped me understand a little better, but not 100 percent...  I see that the spin occurs as the particles are deflected during their approach to the drain site.  But i am still confused a little by the spinning water coming out of my faucet.  Or if i pour a stream of water from a pitcher and i can also see it spinning.

Comment: @MaryAnneRyals how do you know water is spinning? (I'm a curious man in past 17 years I have never seen water out of pitcher spinning) Can you upload a footage  or something? btw the Coriolis effect in drain happens due to water molecules being at different distances from the center of rotation. I will update my ans for a better understanding of Coriolis effect. As far as your pitcher is concerned unless its works on black magic I am really interested in a video showing water out of pitcher is spinning. Use a dye or something to make it more visible.

Comment: Ok when i pour the water i think the patterns i see may be the water trying to disperse according to the dynamics of the water flow and shape of spout as the water falls over it and surface tension pulls this water back together maintaining a stream with sustained ripples.  I can pour cgas carefully and observe increadibly sustained ripples.  Also the faucet water definately spins. Turn your faucet on at a trickle or more and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure the water molecules would continuously mix but spin would would not develop without a circular shape. Also the shape of the raindrop with the tapered tail would prevent it from turning over.
The shape of a raindrop is interesting and some people think it's the most perfect shape for an object to fall through air but it's not. Like natural selection its just what you get but in reality something shaped like an arrow would work better.

Comment: [Raindrops are *not* actually "teardrop-shaped", and do not have a tapered tail.](http://water.usgs.gov/edu/raindropshape.html) This is just a common myth. The actual shape of a falling raindrop is a slightly flattened sphere, not entirely unlike, say, a round bread roll.

Comment: Whatever the actual shape is my statement still stands. It's not the best shape

Comment: True, that part of your answer is correct -- the shape of a raindrop is not the one with minimum drag among all possible shaped. (It also doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question, but it *is* correct.)

Comment: So the flattened round shape is caused by the air pressure and surface tension.  I suppose if the water were spinning the shape would be slightly more flattened.  Possibly different chemical contents might cause differences in surface tension causing different size drops to form, which is sorta what i was working toward even though i didn't mention it in the original question.  Sort of a formula for drop size. Specific surface tension balancing against the air pressure and the centripetal force or just against the air pressure.